# Ajax call : ReferenceError: url is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

MY js code :

```
function OrderFormControllerForRE($scope, $http) {

        var urlString = window.location.href;
        var urlParams = parseURLParams(urlString);

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "http://******:8989/getRuleEngine",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
        }).responseText;

        debugger;
        if (!jsonData || jsonData === "") {
                window.location.pathname = "../html/noDataFetched.html";
        }

        var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);

        if (parsed.error) {
            window.location.pathname = "../html/error.html";
        }

        $scope.ruleEngineJSON = parsed;

        $scope.ruleName = "";
        $scope.priority = "";
        $scope.modifyPriority = function(ruleName) {
                $scope.ruleName = ruleName;
                $scope.priority = $scope.ruleEngineJSON[ruleName];
        };
};

function navigateRuleEngine() {
    window.location.pathname = "../html/modifyRuleEngine.html";
}




function parseURLParams(url) {
    var queryStart = url.indexOf("?") + 1,
        queryEnd = url.indexOf("#") + 1 || url.length + 1,
        query = url.slice(queryStart, queryEnd - 1),
        pairs = query.replace(/\+/g, " ").split("&"),
        parms = {}, i, n, v, nv;

    if (query === url || query === "") return;

    for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        nv = pairs[i].split("=", 2);
        n = decodeURIComponent(nv[0]);
        v = decodeURIComponent(nv[1]);

        if (!parms.hasOwnProperty(n)) parms[n] = [];
        parms[n].push(nv.length === 2 ? v : null);
    }
    return parms;
}
```

My Html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>POC-SalesForce</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js"></script>
    <img src="../img/spinner.gif" id="img" style="display:none"/>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie|Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- The main CSS file -->
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../css/codeReview.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/preloader.css">
    <script src="../js/scriptRuleEngine.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app ng-controller="OrderFormControllerForRE">
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
            <h1><span class="highlight">Modify Rule Engine </span></h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>

<section class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 dateSection">
    <!--<form method="get">-->
    <table id="ruleEngine" class="table table-sm table-inverse table-responsive table-striped table-bordered"
           cellpadding="20" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rule Name</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in ruleEngineJSON">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{value}}</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        ng-click="modifyPriority(key)">Modify</button></td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <!--</form>-->

</section>

<footer>
    <p>Salesforce Free Code Review For Syngenta, Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
    <p>Developed By - Nagendra Kumar Singh</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page the url fires the controller and return the correct JSON format as I can see the results directly in the browser by accessing http://********:8989/getRuleEngine

But when the page is loaded I get this error in the JS while debugging:

```
"ReferenceError: url is not defined
    at eval (eval at OrderFormControllerForRE (http://usblrnagesingh1:8989/js/scriptRuleEngine.js:12:9), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at c.OrderFormControllerForRE (http://usblrnagesingh1:8989/js/scriptRuleEngine.js:12:9)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js:35:36)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js:35:165)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js:68:194
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js:54:298
    at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js:7:392)
    at K (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js:54:163)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js:47:397)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js:47:17"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfunX.png)

I dont know why is it failing because I have a similar page which has `<body ng-app ng-controller="OrderFormController">` and the script has function OrderFormController($scope, $http) {}. It works fine there without any error.

**Update**
I have even tried changing the angular js version, but that does not work. Also this version should work as I have similar page which is working.

Comment: Why don't you try $http function instead $.ajax ?? $http is better and build in angularjs one.

Comment: For consistency purpose we have ajax calls as all of our other js has ajax. But I need to understand why this message is being thrown.

Comment: So this is not even a issue while your app is running but just it throws error while debugging.

Comment: The reason it throws "url is not defined" is because your debug point left that line and moved to another and the scope of that object dies the moment ajax part finishes.Hence when you hover for the url value it says undefined as its part of ajax call

Comment: @Angular_10 No, basically the var jsonData, should contain values, which it is not, as directly hitting the url gives me json format. I showed the image because I can see the values in those reference variables in my other js files.

Comment: it's an http:// error